# text view NullPointerExceptionn

Tags: java, android

I am getting a null pointer exception when running this code :

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        watch = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.wa);
        e = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ed);
}
public  void setTextView(String t) {

        watch.setText("AAAAA");
        watch.setText(t);

    }
```

I am calling the method setTextView on another class this way :

```
 MainActivity m = new MainActivity();
    int counter=0 ;
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        counter ++;
        int min = counter/60;
        int hour = min/60;
        min = min%60;
        int sec = min%60;
        String t = new String ();
        if (hour<10){
            t+=("0"+hour);
        }
        else
            t+=hour;
        if (min<10){
            t+=("0"+min);
        }
        else
            t+=min;
        if (sec<10){
            t+=("0"+sec);
        }
        else
            t+=sec;
       m.setTextView(t+"");
    }
```

here is the xml for the textView :

```
<TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="00:00:00"
            android:id="@+id/wa"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:autoText="false"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="40dp"
            android:paddingTop="40dp" />
```

and the xml for the edit text :

```
<EditText
                android:layout_width="216dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/ed"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />
```

the null pointer exception when calling watch.setText("AAAA"); on setTextviex method 
the logcat :

```
10-11 20:27:42.047 20651-20651/com.example.ahmed.stopwatch E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-11 20:27:42.047 20651-20651/com.example.ahmed.stopwatch E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.example.ahmed.stopwatch, PID: 20651
10-11 20:27:42.047 20651-20651/com.example.ahmed.stopwatch E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-11 20:27:42.047 20651-20651/com.example.ahmed.stopwatch E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.ahmed.stopwatch.MainActivity.setTextView(MainActivity.java:70)
10-11 20:27:42.047 20651-20651/com.example.ahmed.stopwatch E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.ahmed.stopwatch.counterWatch.onTick(counterWatch.java:49)
10-11 20:27:42.047 20651-20651/com.example.ahmed.stopwatch E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.CountDownTimer$1.handleMessage(CountDownTimer.java:124)
10-11 20:27:42.047 20651-20651/com.example.ahmed.stopwatch E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
10-11 20:27:42.047 20651-20651/com.example.ahmed.stopwatch E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
10-11 20:27:42.047 20651-20651/com.example.ahmed.stopwatch E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5476)
10-11 20:27:42.047 20651-20651/com.example.ahmed.stopwatch E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-11 20:27:42.047 20651-20651/com.example.ahmed.stopwatch E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
10-11 20:27:42.047 20651-20651/com.example.ahmed.stopwatch E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
10-11 20:27:42.047 20651-20651/com.example.ahmed.stopwatch E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
10-11 20:27:42.047 20651-20651/com.example.ahmed.stopwatch E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I have tried reversing the setContentView and the findViewById like this

```
watch = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.wa);
e = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ed);

 setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

but it does not work what should I do ?

Comment: please post the logcat too..

Comment: never use the new operator on classes that extend Activity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not how Android works:

`MainActivity m = new MainActivity();`

You should never create an instance of an activity for yourself. They are created by the system, that is why you have to declare them in the manifest. The correct way to start an activity is by creating a new `Intent` object with the context. Check the implicit and explicit intent documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html).

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
context.startActivity(intent);
```

This will start your activity properly calling the onCreate method and allowing you to prepare the views.

Comment: I am trying to use a textView from a new class how can I do this? I could not use findViewById in the new class

Comment: What you can't do is create the instance of the activity. It is created by the system. Apart from that, the rest of the code looks normal

Comment: If you have an activity working, this activity cannot act or perform any action on another activity, if it is what you are trying. The only thing you can do is pass arguments to the second activity to explain what it should do

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't do it like that, You can send your view(your TextView) in constructor and use it(like injection pattern). And do your stuff(ClickListener) with it.